# Add class if image has the class

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have some images which are way too big when I make the menu they're containing in smaller, that's why I made a second class where I changed the width and height.

I tried to add and remove the class with javascript like this:

```
    if ($('img').hasClass('lorem')) {
        $('img').removeClass('lorem')
        $('img').addClass('smalllorem')
    } else {
        $('img').addClass('lorem')
        $('img').removeClass('smalllorem')
    }
```

Now this works perfectly fine, but this will add the classes to my other images on the website as well, how can I specify to only give the class "smalllorem" to the elements which have the class lorem? Because the other images don't have the class "lorem" they will still get the class "smalllorem" added on.

-> I don't get why images without the class "lorem" get into the code? I mean I ask if the image has class .. Why does it include the other image elements?

Comment: you're calling it on all `img` elements and the `else` will always run if the img doesn't have class `lorem`

Comment: Yeah, as @pilchard said, it's your else statement causing the problem. Just omit it

Comment: I don't think your issue should be tackled with JS. When working with style problems use CSS, not JS.

Comment: @Simp4Code I want to add attention again because I want the images to be bigger again when a button is clicked

Comment: And even if I would delete the else statement It will still add the class to other images

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would look for a CSS solution before moving on to a JavaScript one. But answering the question asked...

> I don't get why images without the class "lorem" getting into the code ? I mean I ask if img has class

Because `$("img")` selects all images, but `$("img").hasClass("lorem")` only looks at the *first* image to see if it has the class. Then in each branch of your `if`/`else`, you're applying changes to **all** images (`$("img").addClass("lorem");`). jQuery's API is asymmetric in this regard: methods that tell you something about the element only look at the first element in the jQuery collection, but methods that *change* something apply to all elements in the collection.

If I understand you correctly, you want to:

- Remove `lorem` from images that have it, adding `smalllorem` instead

  and
- Remove `smalllorem` from images that have it, adding `lorem` instead

Basically, you want to toggle both classes. There's a [`toggleClass`](https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) method for that.

```
$("img.lorem, img.smalllorem").toggleClass("lorem smalllorem");
```

That selects all `img` elements that have either class, and toggles the classes on them.

Live Example:

```js
setTimeout(() => {
    $("img.lorem, img.smalllorem").toggleClass("lorem smalllorem");
}, 800);
```

```css
.lorem {
    border: 2px solid black;
}

.smalllorem {
    border: 2px solid yellow;
}
```

```html
<div>lorem (black border) => smalllorem (yellow border):</div>
<img class="lorem" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50.png/09f/fff">
<img class="lorem" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50.png/09f/fff">
<img class="lorem" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50.png/09f/fff">

<div>smalllorem (yellow border) => lorem (black border):</div>
<img class="smalllorem" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50.png/09f/fff">
<img class="smalllorem" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50.png/09f/fff">
<img class="smalllorem" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50.png/09f/fff">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of adding a new class to the image you could just make it responsive :

```
.img {
  width: 100%;      //define width
  max-width: 250px; //restrict the size (can use min-width aswell)
  height: auto;     //auto adjust depending on the width
}
```

```js
var count = 0;
function resize(){
var menue = document.getElementById("container");
count++;
if(count % 2)
{
menue.style.width = "50%";
menue.style.height = "50px";
}
else
{
menue.style.width = "100%";
menue.style.height = "100px";
}
}
```

```css
#container{
border: 1px solid black;
width: 100%;
height: 100px;
transition: 330ms;
}
#home{
width: 15%;
height: auto;
min-width:10px;
}
```

```html
menue
<div id="container">
<img src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/25/25694.png" id="home">
</div>
<br>
<input type="button" value="resize menue" onclick="resize()">
```

Comment: This is also a really good answer, the only thing that is holding me back from using this, is that the space between the object gets bigger when I have my smaller menu chosen. There is no max-right option for that I guess. Right now I'm having "right: 20%;"